# Black Bar Artifact in Cycles Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, artifacts

Attempting to render out a scene and I'm getting a strange black artifact at the top of my render, oddly it doesn't seem to effect the doors, and there is no material overlap. I've tried rendering with and without volumetrics. It does seem to go away rendering in Evee but not the look I'm going for. Newest version of blender, and I've tried opening a new blender file and importing all the assets to new scene. Also fiddled with the light path values to no avail. I'll add the link to my .blend file.
Google Drive .blend file: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1c1alnvr6tNXQ9WZq_rJl8yy_DsTV9732?usp=drive_link

In case of relevancy here is my PC specs:

Processor   AMD Ryzen 7 5700G with Radeon Graphics            3.80 GHz
Installed RAM   16.0 GB (13.9 GB usable)
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor
Nvidia Geforce RTX 3060

Sample Image:
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address the raised issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)